# Were the robots at the end of 'X-Men: Apocalypse' Sentinels?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

Were the robots at the end of [X-men: Apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Apocalypse) Sentinels?

[image]

I assumed they were, but I also heard otherwise.

Comment: Can you clarify what you 'also heard'?, to help explain what you're actually asking about?

Comment: Asked and (kinda) answered [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/53555/when-and-how-did-professor-x-bring-sentinels-in-the-x-mansion) on another stack.

Comment: I live in a group home. A staff member doubted they were sentinels

Comment: He thought they were just regular robots.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### They do appear to be Sentinels.

Visually, they appear to match the 1973 design that the X-Men encountered in Washington DC. (Since they're in shadow, they may have slightly changed.)

[image: 1973 Sentinel Attack]

### Unclear: whether or not they're *actually* Sentinels.

At the end of *X-Men: Apocalypse*, the X-Men appear to be in the Danger Room. In both the comics and the movies, the Danger Room is a training room. Depending on the era of stories, the Danger Room is full of either actual mechanical dangers, holographic ones, or a combination of both. In *X-Men: The Last Stand*, the team ran a training exercise against holographic sentinels in a holographic environment.